# Unable to have an ol3 map in each angular module

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, openlayers-3

I'm using openlayers3 (ol3) and angular 1.5.6 on IE Edge.

I have two modules.  Each has their own controller and component.  Each controller wants to have a map in the view.  One view is for interactively querying data off its map.  The other view is for displaying interactive query results.

Under the hood, I provide a MapFactory which returns an instance of a object, containing the said openlayers map.

**PROBLEM:** The one displays while the other does not.

Here's a sample of my code (some details are left out for simplicity.  For example the dependency injection checks.  All of this code is being called as expected.):

Module A definition

```
angular.module('ModuleA').controller('ModuleAController',ModuleAController);

ModuleAController.$inject = ['MapFactory'];
function ModuleAController(MapFactory){
    var vm = this;
    var vm.map = MapFactory.getMapInstance({
        id:'module-A-map',
        otherOption:true
    });
}
```

In ModuleA's view:

```
<div id='module-A-map' class="map-classes"></div>
```

Module B definition

```
angular.module('ModuleB').controller('ModuleBController',ModuleBController);

ModuleBController.$inject = ['MapFactory'];
function ModuleBController(MapFactory){
    var vm = this;
    var vm.map = MapFactory.getMapInstance({
        id:'module-B-map',
        otherOption:true
    });
}
```

In ModuleB's view:

```
<div id='module-B-map' class="map-classes"></div>
```

MapFactory's definition:

```
angular.module('common').factory('MapFactory',MapFactory);

MapFactory.$inject = [];
function MapFactory(){
    var factory = {
        getMapInstance : getMapInstance
    };
    return factory;

    function getMapInstance(options){
        return new _MapConstructor(options);
    }

    function _MapConstructor(options){
        var _map = new ol.Map({
            target : options.id,
            logo : false,
            view : new ol.View({...}),
            layers : [some,layers,here]
        });

        return {
            publicMethod : publicMethod
        };

        function publicMethod(){...}

        function privateMethod(){...}

        ... other stuff ... 
    }
}
```

Please, let me know if any clarification is needed to answer the question.

**MORE:**
This issue: https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/issues/4601  might be part of the problem.  I am using collapsable DIVs with bootstrap.  The ModuleA is in the default displayed one, while ModuleB is hidden at first.  More to come.

I wrote this up as an OL3 issue as well: https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/issues/5789

**ABSTRACT ANSWER:**

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-events

I need to add a `_map.updateSize()` on a `show.bs.collapse` or `shown.bs.collapse` event.  Now, I need to figure out how to do that in Angular, and post it (unless somebody gets to it first).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, this is in Bootstrap's collapse class.  So, let's back up to the Module-B view.  Each of my Module's is a panel within a Bootstrap panel accordian.  The ModuleA map that displays is the default open panel (the one that has the `in` class).  The ModuleB map is not open by default, and thus, OL3 gives the canvas a `display:none` in the map's div's style.

```
<div id="module-B-collapse" class="panel-collapse collapse" >
    <div id='module-B-map' class="map-classes"></div>
    ....
</div>
```

In my ModuleBController, I simply added:

```
angular.element('#module-B-collapse').on('shown.bs.collapse',function(){
    _map.updateSize();
});
```